# MySQL Same Table Join Issue

Tags: mysql

In short, all data is sorted into rows per value.

I have 4 columns I need to work with, `ENTRY_ID, FIELD_ID`, `VALUE`, and `FORM_ID` which is what I want to use to sort entries per form.

This is driving me nuts because I know it should be simple.

I have 2 examples I need to get out, one being `COLUMNS` based on all `FIELD_IDs` and `VALUES` per `ENTRY_ID` in a row, another that use `UNIQUE` VERSIONS OF THE VALUES AS columns (e.g. think days of the week).

If anyone can help it would be amazing.

Comment: Could you show us some sample data and an example of the result you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to perform some pivoting of your table.

Take a look at this answer:
[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Yeah, I need to create a few different variations. A pivot table makes sense for my first example, but then I don't see where it would take place where I am using some of those values as columns for other values.

Comment: In both cases, if I understood your second example, you need to create some kind of dynamic pivot table, just with different criterias on the columns.